# Bootstrap navbar-brand disable displaying the background image when mouse hover

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I was trying to use Bootstrap. I have met an issue with the "navbar".
Practically into "navbar-header" there is an image. In the code I have an image element with Bootstrap's navbar-brand class. In the CSS for "navbar-brand" class I entered the background color as white.
The his effect is fine until mouse cursor over to image. If it happens the background color is like transparent. I have verify as well with some tool that part could to change his color, because I think that could be of `img:hover` or like something, but nothing.

These images should be show my trouble:
Mouse doesn't cover
https://i.stack.imgur.com/W5Eh7.jpg
Mouse cover
https://i.stack.imgur.com/CAPtD.jpg
(The images size larger than support of site).

Edit: I use compile bootstrap version except for jquery which the CDN I have copied it from bootstrap's site.

This is code that I use:
HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="resource/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="resource/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="StileBootstrap.css"/>
</head>
    <body style="background-color:rgb(230, 230, 230);">
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <span style="display:none" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#remBar"></span>
      <div>
        <img class="navbar-brand" src="resource/Logoskillfactory.png"/>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse" id="myNavbar">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contattaci</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Chi siamo</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Città</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="remBar">
        <ul>
            <a href="#"><button type="button" class="btn btn-default navbar-btn">Home</button></a>
            <a href="#"><button type="button" class="btn btn-default navbar-btn">Contattaci</button></a>
            <a href="#"><button type="button" class="btn btn-default navbar-btn">Chi siamo</button></a>
            <a href="#"><button type="button" class="btn btn-default navbar-btn">Città</button></a>
        </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
/* Remove the navbar's default margin-bottom and rounded borders set
background color and set other property*/
.navbar {
margin-bottom: 0;
padding-bottom:0;
border-radius: 0;
background-color:rgb(230, 230, 230);
}
.navbar-brand {
padding:5px 10px 5px 5px;
background-color:white!important;
}
ul {
-webkit-margin-after:0;
margin-bottom:0;
}
#remBar {
    background-color:red;
}
```

Comment: Some code fiddle please to explain your scenerio. You can create one here "https://jsfiddle.net/"

Comment: If you expect any sensible answers, you need to post a **complete** `code snippet` (HTML, CSS & JavaScript including CDN links) that allows *replicating your issue exactly*. Otherwise, any answers would be based on guesswork and you want to avoid that. [Edit] your question and post your **complete** current `code snippet` there at the bottom by clicking the *"JavaScript/HTML/CSS snippet"* icon.

Comment: I have edited it. I have posted the code to bottom in the question. I excuse.